# git: can merge handle copies as it does renames?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

In mercurial, I can `hg copy` a file, and when I change the original file in an older branch and merge it in to my current branch, **both the original and the copy of the file have the changes merged in**.

I know that git can handle renames when merging fairly well.  If I rename file `originalfile` to `newfile`, make a change to `originalfile` in a branch and merge that branch in, then git will apply the changes made to `originalfile` to `newfile`.

What I can't get it to do is to handle copies.  Git can supposedly detect copies, but if I **copy** `originalfile` to `newfile` and do the same merge as above, then only `originalfile` is changed, not the copy.

Is there any way to have git work like mercurial can in this regard?

Comment: "change the file in an older branch". In Git parlance, this sounds like amending a commit that is an ancestor of the copy operation, so it sounds like you want the copy to change because you "went back in time" and changed the original before it was copied. Correct? (I'm not very familiar with mercurial.)

Comment: So, originalfile is on 'master', and I do 'git checkout -b somebranch' and do the copy, commit, and and go 'git checkout master', change originalfile and try to merge master into somebranch.  There is no amending going on.

Comment: This isn't so much a file *copy* as it is a file *fork*. It seems that you're thinking that if I make a dozen copies of a file to different names, that `git` would keep all of them up to date when I change the original, despite any other changes made to the copies. There are scenarios where that might be useful, but `git` wasn't designed to do things that way.

Comment: @twalberg, Unfortunately, I'm starting to think you're right.  I thought as mercurial had this ability, maybe there was a way to get git to do the same thing.  Especially because you can use --find-copies-harder with git diff to recognize file copies.  I'd accept your comment if it were an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Merging is on a per-branch basis. Since the file copies are on different branches, Git treats them as different files for merging purposes. *(You only merge onto one branch at a time.)*

Comment: If I rename/move the file on a branch though, git has no problem merging because it sees the renamed file as the same file.  So it's nothing to do with branches per se.  It's just I wanted a copy to be treated the same way it treats a move.